# iMac Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017 won't boot after RAM upgrade to 64GB

Tags: imac, hardware, upgrade, memory

Currently my iMac Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017 has 4 x 8GB DDR4 (2400MHZ) OEM RAM installed.

I wanted to max out the RAM to the full 64GB allowed for my model, so I purchased 4 x 16GB DDR4 RAM (2400MHz) to replace the OEM RAM with [Integral IN4V16GNDLRIK2 32GB kit (2x16GB) DDR4 RAM 2400MHz SODIMM Laptop/Notebook PC4-19200 memory](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07YDR5MXK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

But when I replace the OEM RAM with the 4 newly purchased RAM, my iMac won’t boot up (no Apple logo or chime sound) just stuck on a black screen when the power button is pressed. I've left it in this state for a few minutes as I understand it takes 30 secs or so for the iMac to recognise the new RAM, but still nothing.

If I remove all the OEM RAM and install 1 of the newly purchased RAM sticks on its own, the machine boots up.  I’ve tested all 4 of the new RAM sticks individually and all 4 boot up the machine and are recognised.

I can then add a 2nd and 3rd newly purchased RAM stick and the iMac still boots up.  But once I add the 4th new RAM stick the iMac fails to boot and remains on a black screen.

If I then remove the 4th stick and put back 1 of the OEM sticks alongside the 3 other newly purchased sticks the iMac boots up.

Is there a reason I can’t get my machine to power up using all 4 newly purchased RAM sticks? Or is there something I’m missing and need to do? Any help or suggestions would be welcome.  It's as if any combination will work as long as it's not trying to use the full 64GB size.

Combinations I have tried are:

| Boot? | Slot 1 | Slot 2 | Slot 3 | Slot 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | New 16GB* | Empty | Empty | Empty |
| Yes | Empty | New 16GB | Empty | New 16GB |
| Yes | New 16GB | New 16GB | New 16GB | Empty |
| No | New 16GB | New 16GB | New 16GB | New 16GB |
| Yes | New 16GB | New 16GB | Old 8GB | New 16GB |

<sup>* (Tried with all 4 sticks)</sup>

Comment: I *looks like* there may be a problem with the RAM or the Mac itself. As the RAM is easier to replace, I would start there.

Comment: The Amazon listing for that RAM does not explicitly state it can work on Apple Devices. I do hope you are following prescribed methods for handling RAM to avoid static damage.

Comment: In your New-New-Old-New have you tried with more than 1 choice of excluded New?     Does it still work with New-New-New-Old, etc? Trying to rule out that you have a problem with particular slot (iMac faults) or particular module (1 faulty module). Otherwise looks like that RAM has a problem when all 4 are in the Mac. In which case return for refund (as not suitable for iMac) and buy RAM where the vendor explicitly supports 4 in your Mac (e.g. OWC).

Comment: I've now tested Old-New-Old-New and New-Old-New-Old and both boot up and i'm currently running with New-New-Old-New.  I dont believe any of the modules or slots are faulty as all the sticks work when inserted individually or in pairs or in groups of 3. But only fail to work when all 4 are inserted together.  Ive had the sticks replaced by Amazon and unfortunatley the same outcome.

Comment: Well, 56 GB is enough, isn't it?

Comment: @benwiggy 256 meg was meant to be enough according to someone…